# Trying to get property of non-object in Laravel even when it is present

Tags: php, laravel, view, eloquent

the data i am testing on is like this in `feed` variable

```
{
    "id": 32,
    "user_id": 1,
    "target_id": 3,
    "feedable_id": 7,
    "feedable_type": "review",
    "created_at": "2016-05-23 14:18:22",
    "updated_at": "2016-05-23 14:18:22",
    "feedable": {
        "id": 7,
        "user_id": 1,
        "slug_id": 3,
        "review": "y this product is so quite?",
        "stars": 9,
        "created_at": "2016-05-23 14:18:22",
        "updated_at": "2016-05-23 14:18:22",
        "slug": {
            "id": 3,
            "value": "Quite",
            "views": 5,
            "user_id": 1,
            "category_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2016-05-23 14:18:03",
            "updated_at": "2016-05-24 12:47:29"
        }
    }
}
```

but i am not be able to access the value:quite in my view

```
{{ $feed->feedable->slug->value }}
```

Laravel throws

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: ...
```

Comment: Are the relationships properly set on the model?

Comment: yes relationships are fine and work good in plain return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a json variable so you need to decode it first then access the value. Using `json_decode` you can decode the variable and get the desire value.

[Check online](https://3v4l.org/ovWkW).

```
$json = '{
    "id": 32,
    "user_id": 1,
    "target_id": 3,
    "feedable_id": 7,
    "feedable_type": "review",
    "created_at": "2016-05-23 14:18:22",
    "updated_at": "2016-05-23 14:18:22",
    "feedable": {
        "id": 7,
        "user_id": 1,
        "slug_id": 3,
        "review": "y this product is so quite?",
        "stars": 9,
        "created_at": "2016-05-23 14:18:22",
        "updated_at": "2016-05-23 14:18:22",
        "slug": {
            "id": 3,
            "value": "Quite",
            "views": 5,
            "user_id": 1,
            "category_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2016-05-23 14:18:03",
            "updated_at": "2016-05-24 12:47:29"
        }
    }
}';
$feed = json_decode ($json);

echo $feed->feedable->slug->value; //Quite
```